# How to access a table which is present in mysql database in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm a django beginner and now I got stuck with one issue which is - I'm trying to access a table which is already present in mysql database now I want to render that table on a html page, How can I access that table and render it on html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let Django inspect your database table and output a model for it, with:

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

If you want to save the output you can redirect it into a file so you can edit it, because Django's inspectdb may not be accurate enough for you, like so:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py # make sure models.py does not exist before you run that!
```

Then after editing your model, you can use it just like any other model. If you don't want Django to manage it (i.e. not apply migrations), you can set managed = False on your model:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    .... your fields ....

    class Meta:
       managed = False
```

Then to render your model into HTML you can use it exactly like any other model. So create a view, url, and template. If you don't know how to do that, you may want to follow a tutorial:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/

or

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Tutorial_local_library_website

Further info on inspectdb:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/